# Can I use principal component analysis to reduce my data to a single dimension?

Tags: statistics, data-science, pca, economics, factor-analysis

I have a dataset with 10 variables and I am looking to reduce it to a single "score". I understand the basics of PCA, it uses the covariance matrix of the variables to create 10 eigenvectors and 10 eigenvalues. Normally what is done is people multiply the eigenvectors by the normalized data to generate principal components, they pick some arbitrary number of principal components, and throw them into a regression and get the fitted value. In other words, the coefficients multiplied by the principal components allow for a data reduction to a single variable.

My question is whether I need to do the regression step (I do not have a dependent variable). Instead of doing the regression, could I use the eigenvalues as my coefficients? In other words, could I take the inner product of the vector of eigenvalues and the principal component to create a single variable?

I've never seen it used this way (and as far as I'm aware no one has even asked this question), but it seems intuitive to me. Am I missing something or is this legit and I just haven't looked in the right places? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example of when/where the regression step is used? Perhaps there's some confusion in terminology between factor analysis and PCA. This might help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/loadings-vs-eigenvectors-in-pca-when-to-use-one-or-another

Comment: I essentially found my answer [here:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133492/creating-a-single-index-from-several-principal-components-or-factors-retained-fr) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a target variable?
Because there are two things here,

1. [principal component regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_regression) and
2. [principal components analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).

If you have a target variable (a variable you want to predict or explain) the regression if not the second.
PC Regression --> you need a target variable

PC Analysis --> you do not need any regression step.

I think you are in the second case. So you just want to reduce your 10 variables into 1 that summarize everything.

Perhaps and interesting tutorial in Python: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.09-principal-component-analysis.html